# How to disable junk mail notifications?

Tags: thunderbird

Thanks to effective spam filtering, spam email rarely reaches my inbox and the junk folders almost entirely draws unwanted messages. However, I'd likely disable junk notifications especially as the junk folder is included in "unread folders" view:

[image: notification]

I would manually check the folder maybe once a week.

Comment: At some point, Thunderbird stopped fetching junk mail and will only update the folder when opened manually.

Answer (score 2):

In Preferences -> Security -> Junk there is option "Mark messages determined to be Junk as read" - you need to check it.

[image]

See https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/thunderbird-and-junk-spam-messages

---

You can also create filter which will automatically mark Junk messages as read.

Comment: I can assure you that I have the "Mark messages determined to be Junk as read" setting enabled. Seems to only apply to messages which Thunberbird considers as junk, not your email server. I'll try creating a filter, that's a good point.

Comment: I didn't find a way to apply a filter to all messages in the junk folder. Please update your answer if you know how.

Comment: You can try filter by headers and search by some spam-related one (like `X-Spam` or something), but this will depend on your provider and spam software what it is using. I don't know any way to create filter based on Thunderbird folder.

Comment: If you find a way to set a header for every message in the junk folder, I'll accept your answer.